# C++: Convert text file of integers into a bitmap image file in BMP format

Tags: c++, image, bmp, armadillo

I have a text file being saved by a matrix library containing a 2D matrix as such:

```
1 0 0 
6 0 4
0 1 1
```

Where each number is represented with a colored pixel. I am looking for some insight as to how I'd go about solving this problem. If any more information is required, do not hesitate to ask.

EDIT: Another approach I've tried is: `fwrite(&intmatrix, size,1, bmp_ptr);` where I pass in the matrix pointer, which does not seem to output a readable BMP file. The value of `size` is the `rows*cols` of course, and the type of matrix is `arma::Mat<int>` which is a matrix from the Armadillo Linear Algebra Library.

EDIT II: Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124517/c-bmp-to-byte-array-in-a-file) indicated that my size should probably be rows*cols*4 given the size of the rows if I am not mistaken, any guidance on this point as well would be great.

Comment: I suggest you look into this related question: [Writing BMP image in pure c/c++ without other libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654480/writing-bmp-image-in-pure-c-c-without-other-libraries)...

Comment: tried getting some image format library and feeding it the individual pixels?

Comment: Thanks @EitanT, that code is completely un-commented however, and following the programmer's logic is proving tedious. I am working my way through it though, thank you.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you have and what you are trying to do. Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: Of course, essentially I am trying to convert a two dimensional array (or a matrix) to be written into a bitmap image. Something identical in concept to what is being done here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12848/ however, the values absolutely must be read from a text file.

Comment: Do let me know if any further clarification is required.

Comment: Try this.  fwrite(intmatrix.memptr(),size,1,bmp_ptr);  class objects are usually not a direct buffer too the data they represent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an app which generates a text file of random integers, reads them back, and writes them to disk as a (roughly square) 32-bit-per-pixel .BMP image.

Note, I made a number of assumptions on things like the format of the original text file, the range of numbers, etc., but they are documented in the code.  With this working example you should be able to tweak them easily, if necessary.

```
// IntToBMP.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>

#pragma pack( push, 1 ) 
struct BMP
{
    BMP();
    struct
    {
        uint16_t ID;
        uint32_t fileSizeInBytes;
        uint16_t reserved1;
        uint16_t reserved2;
        uint32_t pixelArrayOffsetInBytes;
    } FileHeader;

    enum class CompressionMethod : uint32_t {   BI_RGB              = 0x00, 
                                                BI_RLE8             = 0x01,
                                                BI_RLE4             = 0x02,
                                                BI_BITFIELDS        = 0x03,
                                                BI_JPEG             = 0x04,
                                                BI_PNG              = 0x05,
                                                BI_ALPHABITFIELDS   = 0x06 };

    struct
    {
        uint32_t headerSizeInBytes;
        uint32_t bitmapWidthInPixels;
        uint32_t bitmapHeightInPixels;
        uint16_t colorPlaneCount;
        uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
        CompressionMethod compressionMethod;
        uint32_t bitmapSizeInBytes;
        int32_t horizontalResolutionInPixelsPerMeter;
        int32_t verticalResolutionInPixelsPerMeter;
        uint32_t paletteColorCount;
        uint32_t importantColorCount;
    } DIBHeader;
};
#pragma pack( pop )

BMP::BMP()
{
    //Initialized fields
    FileHeader.ID                                   = 0x4d42; // == 'BM' (little-endian)
    FileHeader.reserved1                            = 0;
    FileHeader.reserved2                            = 0;
    FileHeader.pixelArrayOffsetInBytes              = sizeof( FileHeader ) + sizeof( DIBHeader );
    DIBHeader.headerSizeInBytes                     = 40;
    DIBHeader.colorPlaneCount                       = 1;
    DIBHeader.bitsPerPixel                          = 32;
    DIBHeader.compressionMethod                     = CompressionMethod::BI_RGB;
    DIBHeader.horizontalResolutionInPixelsPerMeter  = 2835; // == 72 ppi
    DIBHeader.verticalResolutionInPixelsPerMeter    = 2835; // == 72 ppi
    DIBHeader.paletteColorCount                     = 0;
    DIBHeader.importantColorCount                   = 0;
}

void Exit( void )
{
    std::cout << "Press a key to exit...";
    std::getchar();

    exit( 0 );
}

void MakeIntegerFile( const std::string& integerFilename )
{
    const uint32_t intCount = 1 << 20; //Generate 1M (2^20) integers
    std::unique_ptr< int32_t[] > buffer( new int32_t[ intCount ] ); 

    std::mt19937 rng;
    uint32_t rngSeed = static_cast< uint32_t >( time( NULL ) );
    rng.seed( rngSeed );

    std::uniform_int_distribution< int32_t > dist( INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < intCount; ++i )
    {
        buffer[ i ] = dist( rng );
    }

    std::ofstream writeFile( integerFilename, std::ofstream::binary );

    if( !writeFile )
    {
        std::cout << "Error writing " << integerFilename << ".\n";
        Exit();
    }

    writeFile << buffer[ 0 ];
    for( size_t i = 1; i < intCount; ++i )
    {
        writeFile << " " << buffer[ i ];
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  //Replace with int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) if you're not under Visual Studio
{
    //Assumption: 32-bit signed integers
    //Assumption: Distribution of values range from INT32_MIN through INT32_MAX, inclusive
    //Assumption: number of integers contained in file are unknown
    //Assumption: source file of integers is a series of space-delimitied strings representing integers
    //Assumption: source file's contents are valid
    //Assumption: non-rectangular numbers of integers yield non-rectangular bitmaps (final scanline may be short)
    //            This may cause some .bmp parsers to fail; others may pad with 0's.  For simplicity, this implementation
    //            attempts to render square bitmaps.

    const std::string integerFilename = "integers.txt";
    const std::string bitmapFilename = "bitmap.bmp";

    std::cout << "Creating file of random integers...\n";
    MakeIntegerFile( integerFilename );

    std::vector< int32_t >integers; //If quantity of integers being read is known, reserve or resize vector or use array

    //Read integers from file
    std::cout << "Reading integers from file...\n";
    {   //Nested scope will release ifstream resource when no longer needed
        std::ifstream readFile( integerFilename );

        if( !readFile )
        {
            std::cout << "Error reading " << integerFilename << ".\n";
            Exit();
        }

        std::string number;
        while( readFile.good() )
        {
            std::getline( readFile, number, ' ' );
            integers.push_back( std::stoi( number ) );
        }

        if( integers.size() == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "No integers read from " << integerFilename << ".\n";
            Exit();
        }
    }

    //Construct .bmp
    std::cout << "Constructing .BMP...\n";
    BMP bmp;
    size_t intCount = integers.size();
    bmp.DIBHeader.bitmapSizeInBytes = intCount * sizeof( integers[ 0 ] );
    bmp.FileHeader.fileSizeInBytes = bmp.FileHeader.pixelArrayOffsetInBytes + bmp.DIBHeader.bitmapSizeInBytes;
    bmp.DIBHeader.bitmapWidthInPixels = static_cast< uint32_t >( ceil( sqrt( intCount ) ) );
    bmp.DIBHeader.bitmapHeightInPixels = static_cast< uint32_t >( ceil( intCount / static_cast< float >( bmp.DIBHeader.bitmapWidthInPixels ) ) );

    //Write integers to .bmp file
    std::cout << "Writing .BMP...\n";
    {
        std::ofstream writeFile( bitmapFilename, std::ofstream::binary );

        if( !writeFile )
        {
            std::cout << "Error writing " << bitmapFilename << ".\n";
            Exit();
        }

        writeFile.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &bmp ), sizeof( bmp ) );
        writeFile.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &integers[ 0 ] ), bmp.DIBHeader.bitmapSizeInBytes );
    }

    //Exit
    Exit();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

If you choose the right image format this is very easy.  [PGM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) has an ASCII variant that looks almost exactly like your matrix, but with a header.

```
P2
3 3
6
1 0 0 
6 0 4
0 1 1
```

Where `P2` is the magic for ASCII PGM, the size is 3x3 and 6 is the `maxval`.  I chose 6 because that was the maximum value you presented, which makes 6 white (while 0 is black).  In a typical PGM that's 255, which is consistent with an 8-bit grayscale image.

[PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) is almost as simple, it just has 3 color components per pixel instead of 1.

You can operate on these images with anything that takes PPM (netpbm, ImageMagick, GIMP, etc).  You can resave them as binary PPMs which are basically the same size as an equivalent BMP.

Comment: This is very useful for generating simple images on the fly, e. g. for data analysis. I used then imagemagick with `convert /tmp/foo.pgm /tmp/foo.png` to convert it to PNG.

Answer (score 5):

To output a readable BMP file, you need to put a header first:

```
#include <WinGDI.h>

DWORD dwSizeInBytes = rows*cols*4; // when your matrix contains RGBX data)

// fill in the headers
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
bmfh.bfType = 0x4D42; // 'BM'
bmfh.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + dwSizeInBytes;
bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
bmfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmih.biWidth = cols;
bmih.biHeight = rows;
bmih.biPlanes = 1;
bmih.biBitCount = 32;
bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
bmih.biClrImportant = 0;
```

Now before you write your color information, just write the bitmap header

```
fwrite(&bmfh, sizeof(bmfh),1, bmp_ptr);
fwrite(&bmih, sizeof(bmih),1, bmp_ptr);
```

And finally the color information:

```
fwrite(&intmatrix, size, sizeof(int), bmp_ptr);
```

Note, that the block size is sizeof(int), as your matrix doesn't contain single characters, but integers for each value. Depending on the content of your matrix, it might be a good idea to convert the values to COLORREF values (Check the RGB macro, which can be found in WinGDI.h, too)

Comment: Thanks for your input, still working through your response. However, what if the matrix was stored in a text file like the question asks? How would you feed intmatrix?

Comment: I don't really know how the arma::Mat works, but I see, there are save / load methods, so you might be able to write something like that:

`std::ifstream f("MYFILE.TXT", std::ios::in); intmatrix.load(f);`

or

`int x; std::ifstream f("MYFILE.TXT", std::ios::in); while(f << x) intmatrix >> x;`
and resize the matrix afterwards with `intmatrix.reshape(2,3);`

Comment: Did you test this code? Regardless of what values of the matrix I put in, I seem to get a singular resulting BMP: http://i.imgur.com/l4zXE.png

Comment: If the range of output values is small (< 256) you can use an 8-bit color-indexed bitmap, and write each pixel as an offset into this array.

Comment: I did not test the code with an arma::Mat, but with x being a simple int (and stepping through the debugger).

If the arma documentation isn't wrong, simply streaming into an arma::Mat should work. However, you need to know the dimensions of the matrix (for the matrix reshape). After that, at least your matrix should be fine. But still your image may not, if your matrix contains only small values. You may want to convert the values to COLORREF values (as stated in the original comment) or use an 8bit color-indexed bitmap, as @Ghost2 assumed.

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten and commented the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654860/586784. I hope you find it clear enough.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <armadillo>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

///Just a tiny struct to bundle three values in range [0-255].
struct Color{
  Color(unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue)
    : red(red),green(green),blue(blue)
  {}

  ///Defualt constructed Color() is black.
  Color()
    : red(0),green(0),blue(0)
  {}

  ///Each color is represented by a combination of red, green, and blue.
  unsigned char red,green,blue;
};


int main(int argc,char**argv)
{

  ///The width of the image. Replace with your own.
  std::size_t w = 7;
  ///The height of the image. Replace with your own
  std::size_t h = 8;

  ///http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat
  ///The Armadillo Linear Algebra Library Mat constructor is of the following
  /// signature: mat(n_rows, n_cols).
  arma::Mat<int> intmatrix(h,w);

  ///Fill out matrix, replace this with your own.
  {

    ///Zero fill matrix
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<h; ++i)
      for(std::size_t j=0;j<w; ++j)
        intmatrix(i,j) = 0;

    intmatrix(0,3) = 1;
    intmatrix(1,3) = 1;


    intmatrix(2,2) = 6;
    intmatrix(2,4) = 6;

    intmatrix(3,2) = 4;
    intmatrix(3,4) = 4;


    intmatrix(4,1) = 6;
    intmatrix(4,2) = 6;
    intmatrix(4,3) = 6;
    intmatrix(4,4) = 6;
    intmatrix(4,5) = 6;

    intmatrix(5,1) = 1;
    intmatrix(5,2) = 1;
    intmatrix(5,3) = 1;
    intmatrix(5,4) = 1;
    intmatrix(5,5) = 1;


    intmatrix(6,0) = 4;
    intmatrix(6,6) = 4;

    intmatrix(7,0) = 6;
    intmatrix(7,6) = 6;

  }


  ///Integer to color associations. This is a map
  ///that records the meanings of the integers in the matrix.
  ///It associates a color with each integer.
  std::map<int,Color> int2color;

  ///Fill out the color associations. Replace this with your own associations.
  {
    ///When we see 0 in the matrix, we will use this color (red-ish).
    int2color[0] = Color(255,0,0);
    ///When we see 0 in the matrix, we will use this color (green-ish).
    int2color[1] = Color(0,255,0);
    ///When we see 0 in the matrix, we will use this color (blue-ish).
    int2color[4] = Color(0,0,255);
    ///When we see 0 in the matrix, we will use this color (grey-ish).
    int2color[6] = Color(60,60,60);
  }


  ///The file size will consist of w*h pixels, each pixel will have an RGB,
  /// where each color R,G,B is 1 byte, making the data part of the file to
  /// be of size 3*w*h. In addition there is a header to the file which will
  /// take of 54 bytes as we will see.
  std::size_t filesize = 54 + 3*w*h;


  ///We make an array of 14 bytes to represent one part of the header.
  ///It is filled out with some default values, and we will fill in the
  ///rest momentarily.
  unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = {'B','M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 54,0,0,0};

  ///The second part of the header is 40 bytes; again we fill it with some
  ///default values, and will fill in the rest soon.
  unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0, 24,0};



  ///We will now store the filesize,w,h into the header.
  ///We can't just write them to the file directly, because different platforms
  ///encode their integers in different ways. This is called "endianness"
  ///or "byte order". So we chop our integers up into bytes, and put them into
  ///the header byte-by-byte in the way we need to.


  ///Encode the least significant 8 bits of filesize into this byte.
  ///Because sizeof(unsigned char) is one byte, and one byte is eight bits,
  ///when filesize is casted to (unsigned char) only the least significant
  ///8 bits are kept and stored into the byte.
  bmpfileheader[ 2] = (unsigned char)(filesize    );
  ///... Now we shift filesize to the right 1 byte, meaning and trunctate
  ///that to its least significant 8 bits. This gets stored in the next
  ///byte.
  bmpfileheader[ 3] = (unsigned char)(filesize>> 8);
  ///...
  bmpfileheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>16);
  ///Encodes the most significant 8 bits of filesize into this byte.
  bmpfileheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>24);

  ///Now we will store w (the width of the image) in the same way,
  /// but into the byte [5-8] in bmpinfoheader.
  bmpinfoheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(       w    );
  bmpinfoheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(       w>> 8);
  bmpinfoheader[ 6] = (unsigned char)(       w>>16);
  bmpinfoheader[ 7] = (unsigned char)(       w>>24);



  ///Now we will store h (the width of the image) in the same way,
  /// but into the byte [9-12] in bmpinfoheader.
  bmpinfoheader[ 8] = (unsigned char)(       h    );
  bmpinfoheader[ 9] = (unsigned char)(       h>> 8);
  bmpinfoheader[10] = (unsigned char)(       h>>16);
  bmpinfoheader[11] = (unsigned char)(       h>>24);

  ///Now we open the output file
  FILE* f = fopen("img.bmp","wb");

  ///First write the bmpfileheader to the file. It is 14 bytes.
  ///The 1 means we are writing 14 elements of size 1.
  ///Remember, bmpfileheader is an array which is basically
  ///the same thing as saying it is a pointer to the first element
  ///in an array of contiguous elements. We can thus say:
  ///write 14 bytes, starting from the spot where bmpfileheader points
  ///to.
  fwrite(bmpfileheader,1,14,f);
  ///Then write the bmpinfoheader, which is 40 bytes, in the same way.
  fwrite(bmpinfoheader,1,40,f);

  ///Now we write the data.
  ///For each row (there are h rows), starting from the last, going
  ///up to the first.
  ///We iterate through the rows in reverse order here,
  ///apparently in the BMP format, the image
  ///is stored upside down.
  for(std::size_t i=h-1; i != std::size_t(-1); --i)
  {
    ///For each column in the row,
    for(std::size_t j=0; j<w; ++j)
    {

      ///We retreive the integer of the matrix at (i,j),
      ///and assert that there is a color defined for it.
      assert (int2color.count(intmatrix(i,j)) != 0
        && "Integer in matrix not defined in int2color map");

      ///We somehow get the color for pixel (i,j).
      ///In our case, we get it from the intmatrix, and looking
      ///up the integer's color.
      Color color = int2color[intmatrix(i,j)];

      ///Now the colors are written in reverse order: BGR

      ///We write the color using fwrite, by taking a pointer
      ///of the (unsigned char), which is the same thing as
      ///an array of length 1. Then we write the byte.
      ///First for blue,
      fwrite(&color.blue,1,1,f);
      ///Same for green,
      fwrite(&color.green,1,1,f);
      ///Finally red.
      fwrite(&color.red,1,1,f);
    }


    ///Now we do some padding, from 0-3 bytes, depending in the width.
    unsigned char bmppad[3] = {0,0,0};
    fwrite(bmppad,1,(4-(w*3)%4)%4,f);
  }

  ///Free the file.
  fclose(f);


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you problem seeing the matrix as an image or writing an image from your code ?

In the former case, just do as Ben Jackson said

In the later case, you want to pass the address of the data pointer of the Arm::Matrix, and using fwrite assumes that Arm::Matrix holds it's data as a contiguous memory array

[edit]
brief look at armadillo doc also tells that data is stored in column-major mode, but BMP assumes row-major mode, so your image will look flipped

[edit2]
Using Armadillo Matrix functions, it's even simpler

```
// assume A is a matrix
// and maxVal is the maximum int value in you matrix (you might scale it to maxVal = 255)
std::ofstream outfile("name.pgm");
oufile << "P2 " << sd::endl << a.n_rows << " " << a.n_cols << std::endl << maxVal << std::endl;
outfile << a << std::endl;
outfile.close();
```