# How to make a bmp header in c++?

Tags: c++, header, bitmap, bmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing BMP image in pure c/c++ without other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654480/writing-bmp-image-in-pure-c-c-without-other-libraries)
>   [C++: Convert text file of integers into a bitmap image file in BMP format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200201/c-convert-text-file-of-integers-into-a-bitmap-image-file-in-bmp-format)

http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html
But how to write these into the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
  WORD  bfType;
  DWORD bfSize;
  WORD  bfReserved1;
  WORD  bfReserved2;
  DWORD bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER, *PBITMAPFILEHEADER;

BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
// Fill your header;
std::ofstream of(/*your file name...*/);
of.write(&header, sizeof(header));
```

You can use any other file implementation instead of std::ofstream.

Comment: Make sure to open it in binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Microsoft article that explains how to store bitmap data in a file.