# C++ reading BMP file works only when row padding is equal to 3 bytes

Tags: c++, arrays, bmp

I have a trouble with reading bitmap files in C++. My code works only when row padding is equal to 3 bytes. Any other padding makes strange things - sometimes I can't read output file and sometimes I can open it but it looks like garbage and have different width and height.

Here is my function to reading data from bitmap file:

```
void read_bmp(ImageFile* Image, const char* filename){
FILE* pFile;
unsigned char* buffer;
unsigned int bufferSize, offset_bitmapData, counter_PixelCounter=0, offset_paddingSum=0;

pFile = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
if(pFile==NULL) throw ERR_FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST;

fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
bufferSize = 54;
buffer = new unsigned char[bufferSize];
if(fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, pFile)!=bufferSize) throw ERR_FILE_READING_ERROR;
if(readBytes_int(0, 2, buffer)!=0x4D42) throw ERR_NO_BMP_HEADER;

offset_bitmapData = readBytes_int(0x0A, 4, buffer);
Image->ImageWidth = readBytes_int(0x12, 4, buffer);
Image->ImageHeight = readBytes_int(0x16, 4, buffer);
Image->FileSize = readBytes_int(0x02, 4, buffer);
Image->bbpInfo = readBytes_int(0x1C, 2,buffer);
Image->Padding = (4 - (Image->ImageWidth*3)%4)%4;
cout<<"width "<<Image->ImageWidth<<endl;
cout<<"padding "<<(int)Image->Padding<<endl;

if(readBytes_int(0x0E, 4, buffer)!=40) throw ERR_NO_BITMAPINFOHEADER;

delete[] buffer;
bufferSize = Image->ImageWidth * Image->ImageHeight * 3 + Image->ImageHeight * Image->Padding;
buffer = new unsigned char[bufferSize];
if(buffer==NULL) throw ERR_BAD_ALLOC;
fseek(pFile, offset_bitmapData, SEEK_SET);

if(fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bufferSize, pFile)!=bufferSize) throw ERR_FILE_READING_ERROR;
fclose(pFile);

Image->PixelArray = new unsigned char**[Image->ImageHeight];
counter_PixelCounter = 0;

for(int height = Image->ImageHeight-1; height >= 0; height--)
{
    Image->PixelArray[height] = new unsigned char*[Image->ImageWidth];

    for(int width = 0; width < Image->ImageWidth; width++)
    {
        Image->PixelArray[height][width] = new unsigned char[3];

        Image->PixelArray[height][width][0] = (unsigned char)readBytes_int((counter_PixelCounter ) * 3  + offset_paddingSum + 2, 1, buffer);
        Image->PixelArray[height][width][1] = (unsigned char)readBytes_int((counter_PixelCounter ) * 3 + offset_paddingSum + 1, 1, buffer);
        Image->PixelArray[height][width][2] = (unsigned char)readBytes_int((counter_PixelCounter ) * 3 + offset_paddingSum, 1, buffer);

        counter_PixelCounter++;

    } 
    offset_paddingSum += Image->Padding;
}
cout<<counter_PixelCounter<<endl;
cout<<"File loaded successfully\n";
}
```

Comment: Seemed to work for me, on a file with zero padding. No obvious errors from reading the code either. Sure is ugly though.

Comment: All those magic number make the code nigh unreadable, maybe you messed one up? Anyhow, there are also compressed bitmap, which you neither check nor handle. I'm not sure, but I seem to remember that BMPs have a separate width (pixels) and stride (bytes per line), which you need to consider, too. BTW, new[] will throw on failure, no need to check and throw macros yourself.

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> A DIB consists of two distinct parts: a BITMAPINFO structure
>   describing the dimensions and colors of the bitmap, and an array of
>   bytes defining the pixels of the bitmap. The bits in the array are
>   packed together, but **each scan line must be padded with zeros to end
>   on a LONG data-type boundary**.

Your code implements the boldface clause incorrectly. You are rounding the pixel count, not the byte count.

Comment: yea... but each pixel has 3 bytes so I'm multiplying a pixel counter by 3 and it's a number of my bytes...

Answer (score 0):

There are four bytes in .BMP files for describing the size of padding in address 0x22 of the file.

You can read it and skip padding. See also this question and replies:
*[C++: .bmp to byte array in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124517/c-bmp-to-byte-array-in-a-file/15637399#15637399)*